# Secure way of storing 3rd party databases/APIs credentials through Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication

I am working on a Laravel app that should allow the user to manually add integration to 3rd party APIs and databases. With APIs it's easy: you only need to store the token. But the user should also be able to add integration with their own databases like MySQL. For that I'll need to store a host, user, password, basically all of the credentials. The issue I'm having is finding a proper and secure way of storing those credentials.

I was thinking about storing all of the connections in a `connections` table, adding the credentials to a `connection_parameters` JSON type field (so there would be flexibility and different types of connections can be stored in the same table) and hiding the details using the `$hidden` property on the model. This would be a first step towards a secure way of storing them, but I'm not sure that's enough.

Do you have any suggestions or practices you've used that you can explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

I can see your main concern is to hide sensitive data from 3rd parties. What you are doing is already "ok" unless someone gets access to your database somehow. You may want to treat those fields the same way you treat users' passwords, since they also contain credentials.

One way would be to encrypt them before storing. Laravel comes with encryption/decryption out of the box https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption.

Another solution is to store each user's credentials in a file and store the file in any directory but the public directory (e.g: `/storage/connections`). This way, only you can access those files. Each file could be named something like `user_1234` 1234 being the user ID. So it's easy to retrieve.